# How I can use MoDisco to create Class Diagram using one project java?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, reverse-engineering

I have a eclipse modeling, I have the papyrus and I have the MoDisco. 
I tried to find some tutorial to know how I can use that tools together and do a reverse engineer. Somebody know how use this? Somebody can put a tutorial?